# Exacting count of link Images

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, html-parsing

I am trying to find the number of images (extensions .jpg, .png , jpeg) with the link through python. I can use any library such as beautifulsoup. But how do I do it. 
I am using following code :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(open('HTMLS%5C110k_Source.htm'), "html.parser")
img_links = len(soup.find_all('.jpg'))
print("Number of Images : ", img_links)
```

But all in vain.

Answer (score 0):

This is as easy as writing a loop if you read the [docs](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

```
import bs4
import requests

url = 'somefoobar.net'
page = requests.get(url).text
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(page, 'lxml')

images = soup.findAll('img')

# loop through all img elements found and store the urls with matching extensions
urls = list(x for x in images if x['src'].split('.')[-1] in file_types)

print(urls)
print(len(urls))
```

Comment: But we are not passing any local path for url. Where do we pass that?

Comment: I think requests library is not imported. How do I install it in python 3.above .I am using Visual Studio code.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use [`lxml.html`](http://lxml.de/lxmlhtml.html) as below:

```
from lxml import html
with open('HTMLS%5C110k_Source.htm', 'r') as f:
    source = html.fromstring(f.read())
    print(len(source.xpath('//img[contains(@src, ".jpg") or contains(@src, ".jpeg") or contains(@src, ".png")]')))
```

Comment: Can we find specifically jpg ,png jpeg ?

Comment: Welcome. You can mark this answer as "Accepted" if it solved your problem